# Mounting a Hive Crone with Harpy parts

Tags: warhammer-40k

I am new in this game and right now mounting my first unit: a Hive Crone.

In the box it contains the pieces for mounting either a Harpy or a Hive Crone.

I already decided I want the Hive Crone, but while mounting it I realized that some parts of the Harpy are coolest - I like the head and the tail more, for example.

I tried to google this but I exactly don't even know how to formulate the question...

So here is my attempt.

Are there any rules regarding mounting a unit with other parts and attempting to play with it?

Would I be able to go to a tournament with my Hive Crone with the Harpy head (that is, without a gun in the tongue, for example)

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can make the head swap. There are 2 rules of thumb for converting Games Workshop models:

**Friendly games**

Here most things go. If you say 'this model counts as a Hive Crone' before you start playing, then nobody will object.

**Tournament games**

The rule is WYSIWIG (what you see is what you get). Nobody is going to complain that they can't see your model's mouth weapon. They know what the model represents. I've not had any problems adding extra legs, spikes etc. to my own Tyranids.

In summary, its your model - you can make & paint it how you like.

Comment: Thanks! That "WYSIWYG" rule, are there any source rule website or something in which I can read the details?

Comment: There aren't any Games Workshop or tournament official websites that I am aware of. There are lots of forums discussing the rules outlined. This is the one I personally like the most: http://www.dakkadakka.com/dakkaforum/posts/list/213703.page

Answer (score 0):

It largely depends on what your goals are. There's basically 4 levels of hobby involvement, and depending on which ones appeal to you, and your skills, it may affect your choice.

**Modeling for the sake of modeling**
It's worth noting, if you just want to make something that looks cool, you can do whatever you want. I meant, if you stick Tau bits on your Tyranids it might end up looking a little silly, but if that's what you want, and you don't care about the game then go for it!

**Friendly Games**
If you are only playing w/ close friends, you can again probably do whatever you want... especially if it's only a few people and you play regularly, it can be easy to track what counts as what. A head swap or different tail would certainly be fine here.

**Friendly Local Game Store**
You are almost definitely okay here too. If your conversions and piece swaps are super crazy some folks might have a problem but depending on the store, you might be able to get away with unpainted marines with no arms attached.

**Tournament/Convention play**
Depending on the tournament this kind of swap is still probably fine. Most tournaments don't strictly enforce WYSIWYG unless you're doing something wacky. If your harpy is a little different chances are no one is going to care, but you could always contact the tournament organizers beforehand to make sure.